# VSCode: disable `end` highlighting for active class

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently I updated VSCode to `Version: 1.87.0 (Universal)` and it did one change. When I've got an active Ruby class tab, VSCode highlight every `end` in this class. Before update it didn't do that. How to disable such feature? I disabled `Ruby Solargraph` but nothing changed. I don't think it's related with `settings.json` but if it is, below is my file:

```
{

    "editor.occurrencesHighlight": "off",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Atom One Dark",
    "editor.fontSize": 16,
    "explorer.compactFolders": false,
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false,
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {



        "editor.selectionHighlightBorder": "#fbf7f7",
        "tab.activeBorderTop": "#12ff00",
        "tab.activeBackground": "#c4111168",
        // "tab.activeBackground": "#98d10a"
    },
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {

    },
    "workbench.iconTheme": "atom-icons",
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.matchBrackets": "never",
    "github.copilot.enable": {
        "*": true,
        "plaintext": true,
        "markdown": true,
        "scminput": false,
        "yaml": true,
        "ruby": true
    },
    "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
    "explorer.autoReveal": false,
    "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
    "vs-kubernetes": {
        "vs-kubernetes.ignore-recommendations": true,
        "vscode-kubernetes.helm-path.mac": "/Users/test_user/.vs-kubernetes/tools/helm/darwin-amd64/helm",
        "vscode-kubernetes.minikube-path.mac": "/Users/test_user/.vs-kubernetes/tools/minikube/darwin-amd64/minikube",
        "vs-kubernetes.crd-code-completion": "disabled"
    },
    "workbench.preferredDarkColorTheme": "Atom One Dark",
    "ruby.rubocop.executePath": "/Users/test_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/wrappers/",
    "git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "never",
    "rubyLsp.rubyVersionManager": "rbenv",
    "workbench.activityBar.location": "hidden",
}
```

Comment: what does the TextMate Scope Inspector tell you about the coloring of these words

Comment: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.